# Socket.io client for Android

Tags: android, socket.io, androidasync-koush

Koush is pulling support for socket.io in AnroidAsync [https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync ], as the socket.io specs have changed. I've had little luck finding a replacement. Is there a similar library that supports socket.io client for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, You can use  [socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) library. Which is the best..

**Edit**

Gottox library stoped supporting since 3 years. Its better to use this library.

https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java

Comment: from https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/59 , I'd thought that gottox didn't support namespaces, which I need. Is there a way around this?